# CakePHP - problem with saving from select field

Tags: cakephp, select, input

i have a problem i can't figure out

in my cake app i have a form that saves multiple data..

one of my input fields is a select field so i have in the view:

```
echo $form->input('Booking.room_id', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $booking_options
));
```

where $booking_options is an array that outputs:

```
Array
(
    [23] => Room name1
    [24] => Room name2
)
```

so when i save the form...
the values in the Booking table for room_id are not 23 or 24 but instead they save as 13 and 14 
where can be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the HTML output of the form ?

Comment: You should show the method where your data is being saved to help identify the problem

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer to your problem, but you should try the Cake way of populating Select boxes properly!

In your controller:

```
function add() {
   $this->set('rooms',$this->Booking->Room->find('list'));
}
```

In your Form

```
$this->Form->input('room_id');
```

This will automatically create a select box with the rooms found in the find('list'), this lowers the chance on errors.

(make sure the 'rooms' table uses the fields 'id' and 'name')